# Monotouch bindings to Obj-c library

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind to an objective-c library with the btouch tool. Should I be binding to a library (lib.a file) built for the iPhone or for the iOS simulator? And what is the difference if any?

Also, does it make a difference if I bind to a debug build vs. release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the iPhone or the Sim version of the .a file really matters when you actually build and run. The sim version of the library is built for the intel x86 architecture and the iOS device version is built for armv6/arvm7 so it is important to link against the version of the static lib that matches what your are targeting. You can make one big library that has both the sim and iOS device .a linked together. If you lookup on Google there will be some walk throughs on how to link the two together.

Comment: Is that what you did when you compiled the [monotouch-facebook](https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/monotouch-facebook) sdk? I'm trying to bind to a 3rd party lib that compresses files ([ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)). btouch generates the .dll fine. MonoDev compiles the project but the simulator crashes with no error when it hits the line that calls the obj-c lib.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did with monotouch-facebook. I forked the official facebook ios obj-c project on github and added some post build steps to automatically create the fat static lib at the end of the build. You might want to do something similar since you have access to the ziparchive code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's what did it for me. I hope you don't mind that I took your monotouch-facebook project as a template for this binding: [monotouch-ziparchive](https://github.com/ayoung/monotouch-ziparchive).